# How to get data ("children" in TreeView constructor) associated with YUI3 tree element on clicking by it

Tags: javascript, treeview, yui, alloy-ui

from example: [enter link description here](http://alloyui.com/examples/tree/)

```
// Create an array object for the tree root and child nodes
var children = [
  {
    children: [
      {
        label: 'File X'
      },
      {
        label: 'File Y'
      }
    ],
    expanded: true,
    label: 'Root'
  }
];

// Create a TreeView Component
tree = new Y.TreeView(
  {
    boundingBox: '#myTreeView',
    children: children
  }
).render();
```

if I add some attrs to children array objects like:

```
    children: [
              {
                label: 'File X',
                internalId: 24342234,
                customAttr: 'unicid',
              }
            ]

  var tree.on('click',function(e){
     tree.get('lastSelected');
  });
```

I can't get them after tree rendering and clicking on this tree node.
All nodes have the following built-in properties:

data    Object  Arbitrary serializable data related to the node. Use this property to store any data that should accompany a node when that node is serialized to JSON.

id  String  Unique id for the node. If you don't specify a custom id when creating a node, one will be generated automatically.

but it does not work for me..

```
 console.log(tree.get('lastSelected').get('label'));
 [gives "File X"]
 console.log(tree.get('lastSelected').get('customAttr'));
 [gives "undefined"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confusing the `Y.Tree` class from YUI with the `Y.TreeView` class from AlloyUI. The descriptions you gave for `id` and `data` come from the [documentation for `Y.Tree.Node` from YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Tree.Node.html), which is used by `Y.Tree`.

AlloyUI's `Y.TreeView` class uses `Y.TreeNode` objects instead, which don't have the `data` attribute you're trying to use to store custom data. Take a look at its documentation: http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.TreeNode.html. To do this with AlloyUI you'll need to add some code of your own. You could extend `Y.TreeNode` for example, adding the `data` attribute to the subclass, and use it instead. Or you can store the data you need in the main node of each `Y.TreeNode` instance, which you can get via `get('boundingBox')`, and then use `setData` and `getData` on it.

Even if `Y.TreeNode` had this `data` attribute though, you'd need to change your code to add the custom data you need inside the `data` key instead of adding them together with the other attributes. For example:

```
children: [
  {
    label: 'File X',
    data: {
      internalId: 24342234,
      customAttr: 'unicid'
    }
   }
]
```

Then you'd be able to get it through:

```
console.log(tree.get('lastSelected').get('data').customAttr);
```

Comment: Maira, i'm using Y.TreeView class from AlloyUI. Maybe it has different way to get some ID from tree-node? I'm trying to get id for model data loading , associated with it (departmentEmolyersList), actually I have department array with child departments, also department has NAME and ID and CHILDREN. I neet to get department id after tree-node-leaf click;

Comment: From what I see in the code if you pass the id to the node with the key `id` you should be able to access it afterwards through tree.get('lastSelected').get('id'),  though you may need to pass it as a string instead of an integer. In your example you were passing it as `internalId` though, which is not an allowed attribute. So you need to either change it to be just `id` or add some code similar to the examples I listed above to store it as extra data on each node.

Comment: Thanks a lot! {id:"number"} it's ok for me.